# NeoMAD build example for Android - reference error

Tags: java, android, eclipse, neomad

I am trying to build a proof of concept app using [NeoMAD](http://neomades.com/). My first step is to install the SDK and build one of their examples for android to test on my phone.

I requested the [evaluation version](http://neomades.com/evaluation.php) of NeoMAD, which I was sent in an email after applying. I then downloaded [Eclipse Standard 64Bit](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) and the [Android SDK 64bit](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#download). I am running Windows 7 Enterprise.

I opened eclipse, and installed the [NeoMAD plugin](http://www.neomades.com/UpdateSite), I was then able to create a NeoMAD project and import the source from their Camera Example app. However when I try to build for ANDROID43 I get an error:

```
Optimizing compiled classes...

Warning: com.neomades.ui.WebView: can't find referenced method 'void setPluginsEnabled(boolean)' in class android.webkit.WebSettings

Warning: there were 1 unresolved references to program class members.
         Your input classes appear to be inconsistent.
         You may need to recompile them and try again.       
         Alternatively, you may have to specify the option 
         '-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers'.
Error: Please correct the above warnings first.
Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)
```

I get the same error when I create a new NeoMAD project and try to build it. Does anyone know how to get this working? Have I done something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't done anything wrong. Indeed, there is a problem with the com.neomades.ui.WebView component for Android 4.3.

The WebSettings.setPluginsEnabled(boolean) method was removed in Android API Level 18, leading to compiler errors.

You can build the application using any older Android target (ANDROID42 for example).

The Neomades team is working on fixing this problem for the next maintenance release.

Updated November 11, 2013: This issue has been fixed in NeoMAD 3.4.3 released October 30.